# Ansible Vault - Same Git repo for Prod & Test

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault, ansible-vault

Apologies for the lengthy post.  I am a relatively newbie to Ansible and Vault (<2 months).

**Environment**:

- CentOS & Win2019 (90% Linux systems)
- Ansible 2.10.7 (master Ansible controller)
- AWX 17.0.1 (embedded ansible 2.9.17)

**Ultimate goals**:

- Use the same code from Git for both environments (Prod & Test)
- Ability to separate the 'secrets' values based on which environment

**Basic Setup (currently)**:

- Ansible master controller is designed to be completely self-starting.  Meaning all the settings/configs are contained within playbooks.  This means I can blow-up the ANS controller and rebuild with 3 min.
- All secrets are encrypted strings within a variable file.  Due to the fact AWX cannot import an vaulted file, all secrets are in-line (*ansible-vault encrypt_string 'secret_data' --name 'my_secret'*)
- Same user accounts exists in both environments but different creds

**Current Issues**:

- If was to import the Git repo into my Prod Ansible master controller, any plays requiring secrets would fail (due it has the secret variable with the 'Test' values)

**Thoughts to resolve**:

- I thought about using the ansible 'default' function for any secret combined with a 'when' conditional based on the Inventory file.  Basically if the inventory file is a 'Test' based system, use 'Test' secrets.  If not, then use 'Prod' secrets.

This is an ugly solution from my perspective and must be a better solution.

- Use Hashicorp Vault.  It has the ability to use namespace trees to classify creds.  I have not played with this idea yet and not sure how viable it is.

I wonder what others in the industry are doing for this same problem.  This is not unique issue and sure there are best practices for this situation.

Thanks

Comment: IIUC you want different variables because on your environment (vault secrets are just another variables)? If so see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout If so, an example: `inventories/prod/group_vars/all.yml` would have prod vault secrets... Using `ansible -i inventories/prod ...`.

Comment: I followed the directory layout provided in the Ansible doc [Ansible Direcotry](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/sample_setup.html)

I followed the 1st example and found it imports into AWX easily.


I read these directory layouts as a either/or scenario.  But possibly I could move the 'group_var' folder from the root level to under the 'inventory' folder.


  - Do you know if AWX will respect that layout?  I will have to test too but will be a few days before I can


  - Is this an excepted directory layout?  I want to stay as 'best practices' as possible.

Comment: 2nd layout is better as you can put variables into env related dir, eg. `~/src/work/infra-ansible/env/prod/group_vars/all/010_cross_env_vars.yml` is symlink to `/sync/src/work/infra-ansible/env/010_cross_env_vars.yml`, which is shared between envs. IMO AWX would work same way as native ansible with recursion of inventory path.

Comment: @JiriB
I wanted to give you the correct answer credit but I can't against a 'comment'.  Can you post your answer as a response to the main post.

If I can do that myself, I have not figured that out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want different variables based on your environment (vault secrets are just another variables) then you could use separate inventories for each environment, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout. Then, for example, `inventories/prod/group_vars/all.yml` would have *prod* vault secrets... You would specify explicitly each inventory with `ansible -i inventories/prod ...`.

In this inventories layout you could share a variable file between environments with symlinks, eg. `inventories/prod/group_vars/all/010_cross_env_vars.yml` would be a symlink to `../../../010_cross_env_vars.yml`, thus pointing to variable files located in parent directory of per-environment subdirectories, ie. `inventories/010_cross_env_vars.yaml`.